# Move characters following some mobility model in UE4

Tags: model, observer-pattern, unreal-engine4, game-development, behavior-tree

Using Unreal Engine 4 , I want to make some of the background actors (humans , vehicles) in my game move following some mobility models like brownian model , random waypoint model , random Gauss-Markov model so that their change in velocity , location and acceleration over time is well-defined and communicated.

Are there any good sources I can refer or can someone please explain or guide me on this (feasibility / process /outcomes)

P.S. : I am very new to game development using Unreal.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Behavior Tree to these things. For your random waypoints, you can use the node, Find Random Navable/Reachable Area, as shown below. You can also set different velocities by setting floats or integers that change every time the pawn or actor moves. For example you could connect random location nodes to a "Set Max Walk Speed" node for your character, changing the rate of speed they walk at and where they are walking.
Hope this helps and answers your question :)

[Blueprints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqTg9.png)